# Copying a dictionary to defaultdict

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, dictionary, profiling

I want to efficiently copy a dictionary to a `defaultdict`.
Here is my code:

```
[In]    from collections import defaultdict  
[In]    new_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e':4, 'f':5}  
[In]    def_dict = defaultdict(list)  
[In]    timeit for k, v in new_dict.items(): def_dict[k].append(v)  
[Out]    1000000 loops, best of 3: 910 ns per loop
```

I want to improve upon the performance of this.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How will you know when the performance is good enough?

Comment: @PeterWood By performance, I meant time taken to run the function.

Comment: optimization for what purpose?

Comment: Since you know `def_dict` is initially empty, you could use `def_dict[k] = [v]` in the `for` loop.

Comment: @morels I am writing a script for which I need to optimise this task

Comment: @martineau This reduces the efficiency ! Time complexity increases 4 folds

Comment: Martineau's suggestion is good. But relative speed of different approaches depends on the size of `new_dict`, and there are also difference between Python 2 & Python 3 (and different implementations). Also bear in mind Knuth's words: "say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: On my machine running Pytrhon 2.6.6 `def_dict[k] = [v]` is almost twice as fast as `def_dict[k].append(v)`. Another option is to use `starmap` from `itertools`, eg: `def_dict = defaultdict(list, starmap(lambda k, v: (k, [v]), new_dict.items()))`. On my machine it's faster than `append(v)`, but slower than `= [v]`.

Comment: @PM2Ring On my machine running Python 2.7.0 `def_dict[k] = [v]` is `8%` *slower* than `def_dict[k].append(v)`.

Comment: @PeterWood: Interesting! How does `starmap` go? (Also, in Python 2 you should notice a minor time improvement using `.iteritems()` rather than `.items()`). But as I said earlier, different versions will give different results. :) FWIW, I get greater speed differences for a small `new_dict` of 5 items, but for 10000 items the differences aren't so great.

Comment: @PM2Ring `starmap` is half as fast. /c:

Comment: `def_dict = defaultdict(list, ((k, [v]) for k,v in new_dict.items()))` is marginally quicker than `starmap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stand by my suggestion that using `def_dict[k] = [v]` would be faster than `def_dict[k].append(v)`, based on my own testing which finds it nearly twice as fast.

Below is the full benching-marking code I used to determine this. I also tried a couple of other possibilities, but none were better.

Similar results were obtained with both Python 3.5.0 and Python 2.7.10.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from textwrap import dedent
import timeit

N = 1000000  # number of executions of each "algorithm"
R = 3  # number of Repeations of executions

# common setup for all algorithms (not timed)
setup = dedent("""
    from collections import defaultdict

    new_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 4, 'f': 5}
""")

algorithms = {
    "def_dict[k].append(v)": dedent("""
        def_dict = defaultdict(list)
        for k, v in new_dict.items(): def_dict[k].append(v)
    """),

    "def_dict[k] = [v]": dedent("""
        def_dict = defaultdict(list)
        for k, v in new_dict.items(): def_dict[k] = [v]
    """),

    "defaultdict(list, <gen-xprsn>)": dedent("""
        def_dict = defaultdict(list, ((k, [v]) for k, v in new_dict.items()))
        """),

    "defaultdict(list, <dict-comp>)": dedent("""
        def_dict = defaultdict(list, {k:[v] for k, v in new_dict.items()})
        """),
}

# collecting results of executing and timing each algorithm snippet
timings = [
    (label,
     min(timeit.repeat(algorithms[label], setup=setup, repeat=R, number=N)),
    ) for label in algorithms
]

# display results
print('fastest to slowest execution speeds (Python {}.{}.{})\n'.format(
        *sys.version_info[:3]),
        '  ({:,d} executions, best of {:d} repetitions)\n'.format(N, R))

longest = max(len(timing[0]) for timing in timings)  # length of longest label
ranked = sorted(timings, key=lambda t: t[1]) # ascending sort by execution time
fastest = ranked[0][1]
for timing in ranked:
    print("{:>{width}} : {:9.6f} secs, rel speed {:4.2f}x, {:6.2f}% slower".
            format(timing[0], timing[1], round(timing[1]/fastest, 2),
                   round((timing[1]/fastest - 1) * 100, 2), width=longest))
```

Here are the results of running on my system:

```
fastest to slowest execution speeds (Python 3.5.0)
   (1,000,000 executions, best of 3 repetitions)

             def_dict[k] = [v] :  0.977644 secs, rel speed 1.00x,   0.00% slower
defaultdict(list, <dict-comp>) :  1.330040 secs, rel speed 1.36x,  36.05% slower
defaultdict(list, <gen-xprsn>) :  1.761532 secs, rel speed 1.80x,  80.18% slower
         def_dict[k].append(v) :  1.929081 secs, rel speed 1.97x,  97.32% slower
```

Comment: But the third result will be different. You won't have the values in lists.

Comment: @Peter: Good point...can't believe I missed that. See updated answer.